# Razor no encuentra propiedades de mi objeto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hola amigos estoy usando Razor y quiero hacer esto

```
    @foreach(var item_voto in ViewBag.Votos){
    Var nombre = item_voto.participante:
   <tr><td>@nombre</td>
}
```

pero me tira este error

```
The operation cannot be complete because the DbContext has been disposed
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: tenes el @model.TuClase al principio?

Comment: @RamiroBarone si lo que se ve ahi es mi clase donde pues si me llega participante

Answer (score 0):

No debes usar var como tipo de dato dinámico para el ViewBag.Votos, debes indicar de que tipo de datos es, en el caso de ser un tipo de dato anónimo deberás crear una clase ViewModel.

Intenta subir un pantallazo o código del método completo en donde llenas ViewBag.Votos en el Controller  para intentar ver el tipo de dato para colocarlo en vez de var.